# Specific table using Divs

Tags: html, css, sass, css-tables

I'd like to create a specific table using Divs, I'd like to implement a fixed header with scrolling functions...

I'd like to add a `scroll-y` to `.body`... And a `scroll-x` to the entire table when needed...

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tonymx227/2nebcy6w/5/)

```css
.grid {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.grid .grid-wrap {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #e54949;
}
.table {
  width: 100%;
}
.table .header {
  background-color: green;
}
.table .header .cell {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
.table .body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100px;
}
.table .body .cell {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-wrap">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">Colonne #1</div>
          <div class="cell">Colonne #2</div>
          <div class="cell">Colonne #3</div>
          <div class="cell">Colonne #4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
          <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
          <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
          <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you use DIV's just to give them a table display? to get your desired result, you should change everything to display:block; give your .body and .header - width:100% as a starting point and go from there.. unless you can explain more what you're doing.

Comment: are you looking for some sort of `overflow:scroll` to be added to `.transaction` or one of the children ?

Comment: Not exactly but `overflow-x: scroll;` for `.grid` and `overflow-y: scroll;` for `.body`.

Comment: What is up with the nested CSS in your fiddle? I tried to fix it for you here

Comment: can you please add the code here too?

Comment: Edit on JSFiddle, my scroll-y bar is hidden...

Comment: Why don't you use tables for this ? It seems like you want to display some kind of data, not doing an actual layout... There's nothing wrong with tables in that case. Then you can use [Sticky Table Headers](https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders) for the "fixed" header : [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jmosbech/stFcx/)

Comment: I need to use Divs for more features that I can not put here...

Comment: And again your CSS is nested. Why did I even waste my time trying to format your code before?

Comment: I use SCSS on JSFiddle... And what's the problem with that?

Comment: about the question... what do you call `scroll-y` and `scroll-x` ? Events ? It is not clear enough for me... What is the desired behaviour ?

Comment: The problem is it does not work here.

Comment: Actually, if you take a look on my JSFiddle, everything works perfectly but only my `scroll-y` function on the `.body` element, this one is on the right of the table... And I'd like to put this one everytime visible...

Comment: If you're using SCSS, **make it clear in the question that you are using SCSS**. Possibly also give the interpreted CSS, as people are more familiar with that and might be better able to help you.

Comment: So, EDIT with CSS...